# Using a custom formula as part of a conditional formatting rule

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Ive got a spreadsheet with 3 columns A, B, C, i want to add the 3 columns together in column E, if there is a value in column C, i want the summed number to be shown in red.

If there is a value in column C, there will not be a value in column B and visa versa, so the logic for the conditional formatting will be something like `=if(not(isblank(C2)), , )`

What im struggling with is how to use the above `if` statement as part of a conditional formatting rule inside of Google sheets, as when i try to paste it in the conditional formatting wizard it dose not work.

Ive created a screenshot of what I've tried so far below, as-well as a link to the Google sheet [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EOA-7pLqj3Xe_y6_HnIzukerzQJ8pNIdDvEI_KzhBWk/edit#gid=0). If you would like to experiment with the Google Sheet, please make a copy using file > make a copy.

Any ideas ?

[image: screenshot of the conditional formatting window shown trying to use the above code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the custom formula `=NOT(ISBLANK(C2))`

Comment: how would i find the max of a range ? Ive tired `=max(a1:a10)` but it dosnt seem to work, see attached screenshot, any ideas ? https://imgur.com/a/t634TF9

Comment: Assuming your (new) question is about highlighting the max value in column A. Use the formula `=$A:$A=MAX(A:A)`

In general, the custom formula expression should return true/false